# EditText in a GridView is hidden by the keyboard

Tags: android, gridview, android-edittext, keyboard

I have some issues with my `GridView` and my `EditText`.

In fact, I fill my `GridView` with my own adapter which contains an `ImageView` and an `EditText`. This `GridView` is dynamically filled when I select an option in a fragment activity. Unfortunately, when I focus an `EditText` to write some text, my keyboard hides all of my `EditText`.

I tried to put this line

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

in my manifest and edit it for notifying some changes, but I saw that nothing happens and I always have the same issues.

This is the XML of the main view which is shown to users

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="161dp"
    android:id="@+id/rlInfosProfil"
    android:background="@color/colorAutumn">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/ibProfil"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/template_card_default_name"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ibProfil"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/template_card_default_age" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/template_card_default_phone"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ibProfil"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/template_card_default_age" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/template_card_default_age"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ibProfil"
        android:layout_marginStart="57dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/rlInfoDetail"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlInfosProfil"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gdInfosDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></GridView>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:id="@+id/rlDetail"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentDetail"
        android:name="pjs4.android.kit.detail.fragment.DetailsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

This is the view of my Object which fills my `GridView`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorListDetail"
android:id="@+id/rlDetailItem"
android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImgD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNameD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="73dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etNameD"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etNameD" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNameD"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivImgD"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pjs4.android.kit">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_cloud"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ProfilActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"
            android:label="@string/app_creation">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I think that it's useless to give you the Java code where I define the `GridView` or my `ObjectAdapter`. If I am not right, you could ask me, I will give it to you.

Besides, I already tried to fill my `GridView` with some static code in the `JavaActivity` and the issue is the same, so I really think that it comes to the XML and the fact that my `EditText` is in a `GridView`.

I tried a lot of solutions found on the net but no one work or are appropriate to my issue.